# How to Extract MFCC features in Java

Tags: java, matlab, audio, feature-extraction, mfcc

I am working on converting a speech recognition project from **MATLAB** to **Java** code.
I have been able to read the **.wav** files (as vectors of values in the range **-1 to 1**) using the java example provided [here](http://www.labbookpages.co.uk/audio/javaWavFiles.html). This works exactly as the wavread function in **MATLAB**.

My next task is to extract the **MFCC** feature vectors from the original sample vectors. In **MATLAB**, I used [Voicebox](http://www.ee.ic.ac.uk/hp/staff/dmb/voicebox/voicebox.html) to achieve this easily but have been unable to find a **Java** equivalent. Using Voicebox, I have a code like:

```
a = melcepst(samples(1,:), 44100)
```

where each row of 'samples' contains the vector representing each .wav sample. The method returns a 2-dimensional matrix of the **MFCC** features for each sample.

I have seen **Sphinx**, but have been unable to understand how to use it for this task.
Any help with using **Sphinx** or any other **java** solution will be appreciated.

Comment: To extract MFCC, FTT values from any audio file in Java, recently I have implemented java program. This program generates Librosa equivalent values of MFCC and FTT. As its not small piece of code so cant post complete code snippet here for quick glance. https://github.com/Subtitle-Synchronizer/jlibrosa

Answer (score 5):

You can get MFCC frames using Sphinx 4 doing something like this:

```
AudioFileDataSource audioDataSource = new AudioFileDataSource(3200, null);
audioDataSource.setAudioFile(new URL("file:///path/to/my.wav", "source");

final ArrayList<DataProcessor> pipeline = new ArrayList<DataProcessor>();

pipeline.add(audioSource);
pipeline.add(new DiscreteFourierTransform());
pipeline.add(new MelFrequencyFilterBank(minFreq, maxFreq, numFilters));
pipeline.add(new DiscreteCosineTransform2(numFilters, 12));
FrontEnd f = new FrontEnd(pipeline);

Data mfccs;
do {
    mfccs = f.getData();
} while(mfccs != null);
```